# Assigning value to a dynamic int variable

Tags: c#, variables, int

I know there should be a simple fix for this, but im braindead at the moment.

I have some count variables set up:

```
int gate1count, gate2count, gate3count;

gate = 1;
gate1count ++;
```

But in some places, I have:

```
gate = someint;
```

How can I increment the appropriate counter depending on what "someint" is?

EDIT:

Ok, the user can select a gate from a drop down menu.  This is what "someint" represents.
So if they select a gate from the dropdown, I need to increment that gate counter.

Comment: I think you need to explain this a little better...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the flags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array instead of 3 different gates.

```
int[] gateCount = new int[3];
int gateIndex = someInt;
gateCount[gateIndex]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like updating `gate1count` if `gate == 1`, then you should probably use an array and do something more like

```
int[] gates = new int[3];

//...

gates[gate - 1] ++; //gate-1 because arrays are 0-indexed
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
gate += someint;
```

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you may need to increment an integer by the value of someint rather than 1 (++).

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll always have a set number of `gate#count`s `switch` statement.

```
switch (gate)
{
    case 1:
        gate1count++;
        break;

    case 2:
        gate2count++;
        break;

    case 3:
        gate3count++;
        break;
}
```